# manage transactions in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have two table and i want insert or update table two with table one.first i select table one and add the result into the resultset.then i select all of the table two records and add them to a list.then i have a iteration on result set and check that if records of table one is in table two then update them and if there is no record of table one in table two persist the new record.but in my code every time persist happens or update is not right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring-servlet.xml");
    PersonManager personManager = (PersonManager) applicationContext.getBean("x");
        Person person=new Person();
        person.setPerson_Name("nazanin");
        person.setPerson_Family("qolamian");
        person.setPerson_Kill("1");
        personManager.registerPerson(person);
        personManager.updatePerson();
}
```

and my personManager0:

```
public void updatePerson() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String getClass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String connectionStringOracle = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
    String userSqlServer = "solaris";
    String passSqlServer =  "myjava123";
    String queryStringSelectFromOracle="select * from people ORDER BY NAME ";
    Class.forName(getClass);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStringOracle,userSqlServer ,passSqlServer );
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryStringSelectFromOracle);

    List<Person> personList =  entityManager.createQuery("select c from person c order by c.person_Name ASC ").getResultList();
    for (Person person : personList) {
        person.setPerson_Kill("0");
    }
    List<Person> personList1=new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()){
        String rname = resultSet.getString("NAME");
        String rfamily = resultSet.getString("FAMILY");
        for (Person person : personList) {
            String name = person.getPerson_Name();
            String family = person.getPerson_Family();

            if (name.equals(rname)){
                if (family.equals(rfamily)){
                    person.setPerson_Kill("1");
                    break;
                }else {
                    person.setPerson_Family(rfamily);
                    person.setPerson_Kill("1");
                    break;
                }
            }else if (family.equals(rfamily)){
                    person.setPerson_Name(rname);
                    person.setPerson_Kill("1");
                    break;
                }else {
                Person person1 = new Person();
                person1.setPerson_Kill("1");
                person1.setPerson_Family(rfamily);
                person1.setPerson_Name(rname);
                personList1.add(person1);
            }

        }
    }
    if (personList1.isEmpty()){

    }else {
        for (Person person : personList1) {
            System.out.println("x");
            registerPerson(person);
        }
    }
}
```

i realy want know how transactions work in spring when it begins and when it closes?can i manualy manage commits or close connections?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring use AOP to make declarative transaction works,of course,you can manually control transaction boundary.

remember,declarative transaction based on proxy in spring, so if you call a method directly, for example in your code snapshot,transaction on registerPerson() method will not work

declare a TransactionTemplate bean in your spring context.

autowire TransactionTemplate into your PersonManager

```
@Autowire
private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;
```

try following snapshot:

```
txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>(){
    public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus){
    try{
        for (Person person : personList1) {
            System.out.println("x");
            registerPerson(person);
        }
    } catch(RuntimeException e){
        txStatus.setRollbackOnly();
        throw e;
    }
    return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: so how i must register person in my snapshot?can u write an example of manulaly control transaction that i can close or commit connection?